# Movie about a man with a hologram girlfriend

Tags: story-identification, movie

I can only remember a specific scene of a man in a chair with a cigarette in his hand, then he gets his hologram girlfriend, I believe his girlfriend, to light it with her finger. Another detail is that she can change clothes depending on what she is doing, for example, she asks the man to dance, and then she changes into a white dress.

Comment: My first thought was "The 6th Day", but that doesn't quite match. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fwTcfwbrNO4

Answer (score 35):

That’s almost certainly the character Joi from Denis Villeneuve’s 2017 movie *[Blade Runner 2049](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blade_Runner_2049)*. The scenes you remember are both in the film.

Comment: [An excerpt of the moment from that scene.](https://youtu.be/9Sffdf9m2Ew?t=170)